# Oracle - ( may be Regular expression ) - Match eighty percent of chars from 2 string literals

Tags: regex, oracle12c

I am trying to match two columns from 2 different tables. I need to pickup records which matches 80% of the chars.

Like tableA has a colA and tableB has colB. colA has a value 'ABCDSEFG' and colb has value 'XAB*CDEFG'.

```
select colA 
from tableA, tableB 
where colA matches 80% chars from cloB
```

=> should return ABCDEFG ( since 80% chars matching to 'XAB*CDEFG').

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `UTL_MATCH` package. One of its functions is *Jaro-Winkler similarity* which returns values between 0 (no match) and 100 (perfect match).

```
SQL> with taba (cola) as (select 'ABCDSEFG'  from dual union
  2                       select 'AB68S33G'  from dual union
  3                       select 'asdfghjk'  from dual
  4                      ),
  5       tabb (colb) as (select 'XAB*CDEFG' from dual union
  6                       select 'ABR8S33GA' from dual union
  7                       select 'asdfghjk'  from dual
  8                      )
  9  select a.cola, b.colb,
 10    utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity (a.cola, b.colb) jw
 11  from taba a, tabb b;

COLA     COLB              JW
-------- --------- ----------
AB68S33G ABR8S33GA         90
AB68S33G XAB*CDEFG         56
AB68S33G asdfghjk           0
ABCDSEFG ABR8S33GA         71
ABCDSEFG XAB*CDEFG         88
ABCDSEFG asdfghjk           0
asdfghjk ABR8S33GA          0
asdfghjk XAB*CDEFG          0
asdfghjk asdfghjk         100

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

You'd add a `WHERE` clause to that query, i.e.

```
where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity (a.cola, b.colb) >= 80
```

in order to return values that satisfy your condition.

Comment: perfect. Thanks.